# Why are all HTML form elements huge with a system-wide font-scale factor 2.0?

Tags: css, firefox, font-size, scaling

I have set the Factor for "Scale for menu and title bars" to 2.0 (see [Ubuntu resolution with Ultrabook](https://askubuntu.com/a/485408/34298))

And I've observed the same behaviour before, when I used instead this setting:

```
org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 2.0
```

in the configuration of my Ubuntu desktop with `unity-tweak-tool`.

### Multiplication of system font increase and browser font increase makes system controls (combobox, lists, drop down lists) extremely big

If you use system-wide scaling all form-elements in **Firefox 29, 30, 31 and 32** are zoomed to double size, which is fine. But **on many websites all through the internet** the **form-elements** seem to be zoomed double (so in this case factor 4.0) for example ***The Trac Project*** had this until they fixed it [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/11607#comment:2).

Why does this help?

```
input, select, button { font-size: 100% }
```

And why does this affect so many sites all through the internet?

### For example the login at [reddit](http://reddit.com):

[image: reddit]

---

### or this example:

[image: trac]

*This Trac [search page](http://trac.edgewall.org/search) still has the problem.*

---

For a fix, I created an add-on that fixes this issue: [Fix for zoomed default-font](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/fix-for-zoomed-default-font/)

But the question stays:

### Why  does this affect so many sites all over the internet?

Comment: While I'm not familiar with the Gnome setting, it's possible it's due to using nested em sizing. But this is just speculation.

Comment: For info: **This is NOT a problem I have in my programming!** This bug occurs on thousands of different websites, so it is of big interest. It seems like nobody ever expected, that someone could use a system-wide zoom factor. But nowadays, with the high resolution displays, this is used more often

Comment: Sounds like a browser zoom issue, or does it do it regardless of how far in you zoom?.

Comment: yes, on all zoom levels. It seems all form elements are resized double by the system zoom level. Ctrl +  and - doesent change the size ratio, it stays that large

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in the end this is a Firefox bug! I posted a report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1031073

Firefox should obey the system-wide scaling if `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` is set to `-1`.

At the moment it doesn't. You have to set this manually to `2` if you want to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a close look at your sceenshot I'd say that your system-wide fonts are set to a very larg size (speaking CSS: `font-size: 200%;`). Why? Take a look at your browser's tab. The size is huge and I doubt it can be sized by CSS.
Thinking on I'd say any element which does not have an explicite font size will take the system's font size - which is huge. As a result, pages will look kinda ugly.

Solution: Set an explicit font size for everything (`*{font-size:100%;}`)

Comment: sure, that's, why my [Fix for zoomed default-font](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/fix-for-zoomed-default-font/) Firefox add-on works fine to solve this issue. The question is, Why does the system-wide-zoom affect firefo to set a default of 200% for all pages?

Comment: I already wrote: because the texts do not have an explicit font size. I guess that all texts without explicit size get the system's font size.

Comment: no, look at [this examle](https://gist.github.com/rubo77/c993a18eefbe3af9a767) without any css definitions (download it raw, open it locally and see the differences in your Unity desktop when you zoom)